# 'GeneratedDotEnv.m' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm creating a react native app in which I use react-native-config for building different versions. I'm getting this error when trying to archive the project. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this [link](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config/issues/187#issuecomment-353156419) and you'll be able to fix it.

or
I recommend applying this method.

Using RN 0.53.0.

Basically the process is to:

- add the ../node_modules/react-native-config/ios/ReactNativeConfig.xcodeproj to 
  your own project
- In your Target settings, Build Phases, Link Binary With Libraries, add 
  libReactNativeConfig.a.
- Manage scheme, expand "Build", click "Pre-actions", "New Run Script Action", 
  enter:

  if [ "${ENVFILE}" ]; then echo "${ENVFILE}" > /tmp/envfile ; else echo ".env" > /tmp/envfile; fi
- Ensure your .env.prod file has some key/values without spaces around the = like 
  I've been seeing around these threads. Then run in term: $ ENVFILE=.env.prod 
  react-native run-ios.

Please refer to [this link](https://github.com/Clintal/react-native-config/tree/ios-manual-linking#manual-linking-ios) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Add below `post_install` script to your podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
targets_to_ignore = %w(React)

if targets_to_ignore.include? target.name
  target.remove_from_project
end

if target.name == 'react-native-config'
  phase = target.project.new(Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXShellScriptBuildPhase)
  phase.shell_script = "cd ../../"\
                       " && RNC_ROOT=./node_modules/react-native-config/"\
                       " && export SYMROOT=$RNC_ROOT/ios/ReactNativeConfig"\
                       " && export BUILD_DIR=$RNC_ROOT/ios/ReactNativeConfig"\
                       " && ruby $RNC_ROOT/ios/ReactNativeConfig/BuildDotenvConfig.ruby"

  target.build_phases << phase
  target.build_phases.move(phase,0)
end
end
end
```

Please Refer this [GitHub-Issue](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config/issues/187#issuecomment-468730417)

Comment: https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config/issues/125#issuecomment-350119869 is same like your answer except a little bit command changes that resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I put `pod 'react-native-config', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-config'` inside `Podfile`

```
...
target 'app' do
  ...
  pod 'react-native-config', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-config'
  ...
end
```

And this works for me.

My versions:

```
 "react": "18.1.0"
 "react-native": "0.70.4",
 "react-native-config": "1.4.4"
```

I downgrade `react-native-config` from `1.4.11` to `1.4.4`